# updating a sql 2005 database using text boxes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

I have a VB.Net form which allows the user to update the customer details such as name, contact no:, etc. So when the customer enters the new name for the customer name etc. the application should update the corresponding field in the existing entry that relates to the customer ID.

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable

cn.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=NIMO-HP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FYP_db;Integrated Security=True")
cmd.Connection = cn
cn.Open()

cmd.CommandText = " UPDATE TblCustomerDetails (compID, compName, compContact, compAddress, compFax, compEmail, compPayterm, compTaxscheme, compPaymode, compRemarks ) SET Values ('" & lblCID.Text & "', '" & txtCname.Text & "', '" & txtCpno.Text & "', '" & txtCaddrs.Text & "','" & txtCfax.Text & "', '" & txtCemail.Text & "', '" & cmbPterm.Text & "','" & cmbTaxschm.Text & "',' " & cmbPmode.Text & "', '" & txtRemarks.Text & "')  WHERE compID = '" & lblCID.Text & "';"

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("Account updated!!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Updation complete")
```

Comment: Rise the question clearly.

Comment: SQL Injection with this style - use [parameterized queries](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=parameterized%20queries&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codinghorror.com%2Fblog%2F2005%2F04%2Fgive-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html&ei=bCvYUeDpGqGzyQHOvoHYDQ&usg=AFQjCNHt4QN4NLsK12Zt-C7BXPFquF4yGw&bvm=bv.48705608,d.aWc). What are your issues? Errors?

Comment: companyID , company name, contact, address, fax are the data fields in the database.now i want to update the database using the texts entered to te text boxes.. above is the code i have used to update the database, using text boxes

Comment: when i run the program it says  "Incorrect syntax near '('   "
but i cant find what is wrong with the code... need help to solve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using a INSERT syntax for your UPDATE statement.  Your UPDATE statement should have the form:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    col1 = val1,
       col2 = val2,
       col3 = val3
WHERE  someColumn = someValue
```

Additionally, you are wide open to SQL Injection attacks by using non-parameterized queries.  Finally, I would use a `Using` blocks to ensure your connection and command are properly closed and disposed of.

Putting it all together it would look something like this:

```
Using Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=NIMO-HP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FYP_db;Integrated Security=True")

    cn.Open()

    Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE TblCustomerDetails " + _
                             "SET compName = @compName, " + _
                             "compContact = @compContact, " + _
                             "compAddress = @compAddress, " + _
                             "compFax = @compFax, " + _
                             "compEmail = @compEmail, " + _
                             "compPayterm = @compPayterm, " + _
                             "compTaxscheme = @compTaxscheme, " + _
                             "compPaymode = @compPaymode, " + _
                             "compRemarks = @compRemarks " + _
                             "WHERE compID = @compID"

    Using Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compFax", txtCname.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compContact", txtCpno.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compAddress", txtCaddrs.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compFax", txtCfax.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compEmail", txtCemail.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compPayterm", cmbPTerm.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compTaxscheme", cmbTaxschm.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compPaymode", cmbPmode.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compRemarks", txtRemarks.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compID", lblCID.Text)

        Dim result As Integer

        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If result = 1 Then
            MsgBox("Account updated!!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, _
                   "Updation complete")
        Else
            MsgBox("Account not updated!!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, _
                   "Updation not complete")
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

There are a few more things to note in the above code sample:

First, I removed compID from the list of values to update.  You're using that in your WHERE query, so I think you would have interesting results in your query if you're trying to update the same column you are using as part of your WHERE clause. Additionally, the source for that value is a Label, which tells me it's not supposed to be changed.

Secondly, `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns an int with the number of rows affected.  In this case, it should be 1 - if it's not 1, I have you show a different message box.

Thirdly, `cmbPTerm`, `cmbTaxxshm` and `cmbPmode` sound like `ComboBox` to me, and you're not going to get what I think you're expecting using their `Text` property.  I think you'll want `SelectedText` - hard to say without knowning how your ComboBoxes are bound.  I'll leave that as an exercise for you :)

Fourth, I broke the UPDATE query up across several lines simply for readability - you don't have to do it that way, as long as the query is correct.

Finally, I'd suggest using `MessagBox.Show()` vs `MsgBox`.

Comment: thanx for the your kind support @Tim , and at the mean time i have figured out a solution that worked for this problem. and it is given below.. Once again, i really appreciate your support.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim cnn As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    cnn.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=NIMO-HP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FYP_db;Integrated Security=True")
    cmd.Connection = cnn
    cnn.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "update TblCustomerDetails set compName='" & txtCname.Text & "' , compContact = '" & txtCpno.Text & "' , compAddress = '" & txtCaddrs.Text & "' , compFax = '" & txtCfax.Text & "' , compEmail = '" & txtCemail.Text & "' , compPayterm = '" & cmbPterm.Text & "' , compTaxscheme = '" & cmbTaxschm.Text & "' , compPaymode = '" & cmbPmode.Text & "' , compRemarks = '" & txtRemarks.Text & "' where compID = '" & lblCID.Text & "'"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cnn.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("entry updated!!!")
```