# Update statement won't execute as expected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Just seeking for answers why my Update Statement won't execute as expected. I have created a Stored Procedure in SQL Server named as 'Update_Employee', then I called the procedure in my VB.Net to update records. This is what i have done so far :

VB.net

```
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conEmployee").ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "Update_Employee"

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = lblIDNum.Text.Trim
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text.Trim
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empAdd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text.Trim
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empPhone", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPhone.Text.Trim
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text.Trim

    cmd.Connection = con

    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Stored Proc Script:

```
USE [Company]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Update_Employee]    Script Date: 08/20/2015 11:20:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Employee]

  @empID int,
  @empName varchar(50),
  @empAdd varchar(50),
  @empPhone nchar(11),
  @empEmail varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      UPDATE  tbl_EMPLOYEE SET EMP_NAME = @empName, EMP_ADD = @empAdd, EMP_PHONE = @empPhone, EMP_EMAIL = @empEmail
      WHERE EMP_ID = @empID
END
```

Comment: Please don't ever code `Catch ex As Exception Throw ex`. That's just going to cause you grief. As for the rest of the `Try` block you should use `Using` instead.

Comment: Change `con.Open()` to `cmd.Connection.Open()`. In your example your opening it first before hand. Then when you call your executenonquery its not going to have an open connection as its already open...

Comment: What's _won't execute as expected_? doesn't make any changes? makes the wrong changes? Does the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` line run when you execute your code in debug?? Are you absolutely certain the empID's match between the form and the table? Are you certain you're running this in the correct database? A quick way to find out is to use SQL Profiler.

Comment: Hi.. I'm gone modifying the source codes.. but got no success.. codes posted above doesn't make any changes to database records.

Comment: @cliecel john Show your connection string...

Answer (score 0):

Did you give the application access to execute the new SP?

Grant Execute on Update_Employee to (application login id)

Answer (score -1):

Check out [updating a sql 2005 database using text boxes in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503778/updating-a-sql-2005-database-using-text-boxes-in-vb-net).

Check out Tim's exlpaination